# LINQ one-to-many: how to delete am entity that has references

Tags: c#, linq, one-to-many

I have 2 tables in my database:

```
[Table]
public class Names: INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyPropertyChanging
{        
    public Names()
    {
        this._namesCar = new EntitySet<Coord>(this.OnCarAdded, this.OnCarRemoved);
    }

    private int _id;
    private string _name;
    private EntitySet<Cars> _namesCar;

    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, DbType = "INT NOT NULL Identity", CanBeNull = false, AutoSync= AutoSync.OnInsert)]
    public int Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set
        {
            if (_id != value)
            {
                NotifyPropertyChanging("Id");
                _id = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Id");
            }
        }
    }

    [Column]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            if (_name != value)
            {
                NotifyPropertyChanging("Name");
                _name = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }

    [Association(Storage = "_namesCar", ThisKey = "Id", OtherKey = "NamesId")]
    public EntitySet<Cars> NamesCar
    {
        get { return _namesCar; }
        set
        {
            if (_namesCar != value)
            {
                NotifyPropertyChanging("NamesCar");
                _namesCar = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("NamesCar");
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnCarAdded(Cars car)
    {
        car.Name= this;
    }

    private void OnCarRemoved(Cars car)
    {
        car.Name= null;
    }
```

and

```
[Table]
public class Cars: INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyPropertyChanging
{

    private int _id;
    private int _nameid;
    private string _cars;        
    private EntityRef<Names> _carNames = new EntityRef<Names>();

    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, DbType = "INT NOT NULL Identity", CanBeNull = false, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
    public int Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set
        {
            if (_id != value)
            {
                NotifyPropertyChanging("Id");
                _id = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Id");
            }
        }
    }

    [Column(DbType = "Int")]
    public int NameId
    {
        get { return _nameid; }
        set
        {
            if (_nameid != value)
            {
                NotifyPropertyChanging("NameId");
                _nameid = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("NameId");
            }
        }
    }

    [Association(Storage = "_carNames", ThisKey = "NameId", OtherKey = "Id", IsForeignKey = true)]
    public Names Names
    {
        get { return this._carNames.Entity; }
        set
        {
            NotifyPropertyChanging("Names");
            this._carNames.Entity = value;
            if (value != null)
            {                    
                this._nameid = value.Id;
            }
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Names");
        }
    }
```

They belong to the same datacontext:

```
public class CarsDataContext : DataContext
{
    // Pass the connection string to the base class.
    public CarsDataContext(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    { }

    // Specify a table for the items.
    public Table<Names> RecNames;
    public Table<Cars> RecCars;

}
```

I can add a new name and then add new cars associated with that name. I can also delete cars from one name. However when I try to delete a name I m getting an exception. I believe it is because  have cars associated with that name. What would be the best way to delete a name that contains cars associated to it? My intention is to delete all cars first and then delete the name.

Thanks!

Comment: It would be helpful to know what exception you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [`DeleteRule`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.associationattribute.deleterule.aspx) property of the `Association` attribute, specifically using "CASCADE" as indicated in the remarks:

> If set to null, no delete behavior is added. For example, "CASCADE"
>   would add "ON DELETE CASCADE" to the foreign-key relationship.